# Prolog - if condition 1 AND condition 2 do x

Tags: prolog

I want to write the equivalent psudo-function in prolog:

```
function underhundred(X){

    if (X >= 0 && X <=100) return 1;
    else return 0;

}
```

I tried writing this but it does not compile:

```
underhundred(X,L) :- L is (X => 0, X =< 100 -> L = 1; L = 0) .
```

What would be the proper way of writing this without using prolog between predicate?

Answer (score 3):

If you indeed want to use the goals `L=1` and `L=0` and `X` is an integer, use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Reification works like a charm!

```
?- X in 0..100 #<==> L.
L in 0..1, X in 0..100#<==>L.
```

What if `X` gets instantiated?

```
?- X in 0..100 #<==> L, X=(-7).
L = 0, X = -7.                    % out of bounds: -7 < 0       =< 100

?- X in 0..100 #<==> L, X=55.
L = 1, X = 55.                    % within bounds:      0 =< 55 =< 100

?- X in 0..100 #<==> L, X=111.   
L = 0, X = 111.                   % out of bounds:      0       =< 100 < 111
```

Comment: How would you answer this question to accept real numbers?

Comment: @user27815. If you are interested in floating-point arithmetics... `(is)/2` does that. Or do you want constraint solving over floating point or rational numbers? Then, consider using [tag:clpq] and/or [tag:clpr]. If you want something like `X in 0..100 #<==> L, X = 111`, not over integers, but over floating point (or arbitrary-precision ratonal) numbers, check if a question that fits your needs has already been posted. If not, post a new question.

Comment: Well this question does not specify that the function should only work on integers. So I thought it might be a good place to provide an answer that does both.

Comment: @user27815. I agree that the question does not explicitly specify the domain. But all numbers used by the OP are integers. Moreover, the OP mentions the Prolog predicate `between/3`, which is only works with integers.

Answer (score 0):

A Prolog query succeeds or fails. If it succeeds it will return the bindings it made to be true.

You can write this predicate using clpfd as:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

under_hundred_clpfd(X):-
X in 0..100.
```

(You might prefer a name such as between_0_100?, if you literally want under 100 then you can use X in inf..99).
Some queries:

```
?-under_hundred_clpfd(5).
true.

?-under_hundred_clpfd(101).
false.

?-under_hundred_clpfd(X).
X in 0..100.
```

A traditional way to write this is:

```
 under_hundred(X):-
 X>=0,
 X=<100.
```

But this way does not work for uninstantiated variables.

```
?-under_hundred(X).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

So like you say you might have to put a between/3 or length/2 goal to get a solution or similar construct.

```
underhundred(X):-
  length(_,X),
  X>=0,
  X=<100.
```

This is not a very good solution as on back tracking it will get into an infinite loop. between/3  behaves better but you don't want it :).

Comment: The OP wanted to "return 1" or "return 0" and specified `underhundred/2` (not `underhundred/1`). How about switching to arity 2 and writing a second clause for the alternative case?

Comment: I was just trying to make the point that in reality you probably don't want to return a 1 or zero.  As the success or failure of the goal conveys that information..

Comment: I see. If you want to use the predicate as the condition of some if-then-else (like `(->)/2` or `(*->)/2` or `if/3`), logical soundness is easily lost, and with it other nice algebraic properties! This is even more severe with clpfd constraints, as these are often not immediately decided but delayed and executed at some later time (typically triggered by `labeling/2`). Above control constructs can **all** ruin the logical meaning whenever they **commit too early**. If we reify the truthfulness of `underhundred` with an extra argument, however, we can avoid these problems alltogether!

Comment: I try not to use if-then-else :)

Comment: Bottom line: if-then-else or negation or cut plus clpfd = havoc! Wrong answers, with no warning signs whatsoever! `is/2` raises instantiation errors in these cases, clpfd does not. Beware!

Answer (score 0):

If the main point of the question is how to write an if-then-else construct in Prolog, then a reasonable answer along the lines of the proposed definition is:

```
underhundred(X,L) :-
   (  X >= 0, X =< 100  )
   -> L = 1
   ;  L = 0.
```

This will only be useful if `underhundred(X,L)` is called after `X` has been sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: The last layout changes you did are questionable.  cf http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2899

Comment: @repeat -- I take my inspiration from this recommendation in that paper: "Programmers do not remember the relative precedence of commas and semicolons; a,b;c means (a,b);c but this fact is not obvious. Thus, layout and parentheses to indicate precedence are recommended."  Omitting the outer parentheses is fine here as the entire body of the clause is just one if-then-else statement.